# How to read multiple column CSV by changing headers into categories and all values into one column?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to create a multiple-line chart in d3.js, the data is in csv and is organized as follows:

```
¦Date      ¦ Cat A¦ Cat B¦ Cat C¦  
¦:---------¦:----:¦:----:¦-----:¦  
¦2019-12-01¦2     ¦6     ¦9     ¦  
¦2018-11-02¦4     ¦4     ¦20    ¦
```

How do I read the data to be arranged into three columns:

```
¦Date      ¦ Category¦ value ¦  
¦:---------¦:-------:¦------:¦  
¦2019-12-01¦CAT A    ¦2      ¦  
¦2018-11-02¦CAT A    ¦4      ¦  
¦2019-12-01¦CAT B    ¦6      ¦  
¦2018-11-02¦CAT B    ¦9      ¦
```

Please note that I would like to ignore one of the columns (CAT C)

Comment: If any mods are passing through here - table markdown is broken.

Comment: do you want the final result to be a string like you posted or an array of javascript objects that can be used in d3?

Comment: A final result to be used in d3 would be great. Also, If you could suggest a string-separated format that would be good to know as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically in D3, one imports flattened data and then groups or nests it accordingly. This means (as far as I'm aware) the tools for doing the reverse aren't quite so natural. In this case it may be straightforward and readable to use vanilla Javascript:

```
    const data = [
        { Date: '2019-12-01', 'A' : 2, 'B' : 6, 'C' : 9  }, 
        { Date: '2018-11-02', 'A' : 4, 'B' : 4, 'C' : 20 }
    ];
    
    console.log(data)
    
    result = [];
    
    data.forEach(row => {
                 let a = (({ Date, A, B, C }) => ({ Date, A}))(row);
                 result.push(a)
                 let b = (({ Date, A, B, C }) => ({ Date, B}))(row);
                 result.push(b)
                 });
    console.log(result);
```